# Is there a way to make a class to give me the instance of current user in ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

Is there a way to create a class in ASP.NET identity that gives me the current user who is logged into my system? I need all of his details
instead of call the User Manager each time I want to access to its details.

I am trying to make a class to give all the details of the logged in user in ASP.NET identity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear :(

Do you want to store additional user information in the ClaimsIdentity when the user logs in? That can be achieved by a class implementing the [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims) interface. I would not recommend writing sensitive information into the claims though.

If you want to access the user's information, you can use the HttpContext.User. The current HttpContext can be accessed via the [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could add the user infomration inside the claims instead of creating a new instance inside your application. But please notice, we don't suggest you store the importent user information inside the claims, since the claims will be stored as cookie inside user side. By using claims, we could get more information for that user.

More details about how to do it, you could refer to below codes:

Crete a UserClaimsPrincipalFactory and register it inside the DI.

```
public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>
{
    public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        //You could store more claims into the cookie, then you could directly read the more user proerpty instead of using user manager
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("PhoneNumber", user.PhoneNumber ?? "[11223344]"));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

Inside the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Result:

[image]